# JmsTemplate open and close connection with Java

Tags: java, spring, jmstemplate

Can anyone give me an example of how to open and close a connection to a queue using JmsTemplate?

At the moment I am reading a lot of messages from a queue using the
`receiveSelected()` method.  However, every time I read a message the `org.springframework.jms.connection.singleconnectionfactory` open and closes a connection for each message the application reads.

I would like instead to open a connection read lots of messages from a queue and then close the connection.

Thanks

Comment: Use a CachingConnectionFactory instead.

Comment: Thank you fateddy. With CachingConnectionFactory works perfectly